# C++ if else if else statement for output

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int KUnit;
    float K;
    cout << "Enter 0 for SI Units and Press 1 for US customary units: ";
    cin >> KUnit;
    
    if (KUnit == 0)
    {
        cout << "k = " << K << " watts/mK" << endl;
    }
    else if (KUnit == 1)
    {
        cout << "k = " << K << " BTU/hr-ft F deg" << endl;
        K = K * 0.5779;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid unit, please try again";
        return 1;
    }
// output
    cout << "Thermal Conductivity " << K << KUnit << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output becomes `Thermal Conductivity 0.290` or `Thermal Conductivity 0.291`

The output adds a 0 or 1 coming from the initial prompt. I'm not sure if there's a way for me to change it. Is there a way for `KUnit` to output  `"watts/mK"` or `"BTU/hr-ft F deg"` as the user inputs 0 or 1? Using an `if-else` structure.

Answer (score 2):

Cache the units in a variable on your way through the existing `if` statement ladder and print it out in the output line.
Eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    int KUnit;
    float K;

    // Added: get value from user
    std::cout << "Enter value to convert: ";
    std::cin >> K;

    std::string units; // Added: holds user-provided units
    std::cout << "Enter 0 for SI Units and Press 1 for US customary units: ";
    std::cin >> KUnit;

    if (KUnit == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "k = " << K << " watts/mK" << std::endl;
        units = "watts/mK"; // added: store metric units
    }
    else if (KUnit == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "k = " << K << " BTU/hr-ft F deg" << std::endl;
        K = K * 0.5779;
        units = "BTU/hr-ft F deg"; // added: store imperial units
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid unit, please try again";
        // added: nothing to store
        return 1;
    }
// output. changed: displays units.
    std::cout << "Thermal Conductivity " << K << units << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could store the text "watts/mK"/"BTU/hr-ft F deg" on a string and then, print it:

```
int main() {
    int KUnit;
    float K;
    cout << "Enter 0 for SI Units and Press 1 for US customary units: ";
    cin >> KUnit;

    std::string KUnitStr;
    if (KUnit == 0) {
        KUnitStr = " watts/mK";
    } else if (KUnit == 1) {
        KUnitStr =  " BTU/hr-ft F deg";
        K = K * 0.5779;
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid unit, please try again";
        return 1;
    }

    // output
    cout << "k = " << K << KUnitStr << endl;
    cout << "Thermal Conductivity " << K << KUnitStr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```